# Is it possible to install the same version of ubuntu on the same hdd?

Tags: grub2, nvidia, partitioning, nvidia-optimus

I would like to have ubuntu 14.04 installed two times on my laptop. One is for actual day to day use, the other for testing how ubuntu copes with my hardware under different circumstances, without destroying my working environment. Mostly this is because I want to test how ubuntu 14.04 handles the nvidia optimus card the laptop has installed, without breaking the actual working environment that I need.

Will this screw up grub or anything? I plan to do this second install on a seperate partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any problems as long as you use a seperate partition of course.

It will show as 2 different operating systems in GRUB, so you can choose.

Of course you can screw up GRUB (if you are experimenting with GRUB) because both operating systems will use the same GRUB. This won't affect the operating systems themselves so it will be easy to fix using a live CD or something like that.

And of course you shouldn't mount the FS of your 'stable' Ubuntu on the 'unstable' one, just to be safe.

Comment: Will try installing 14.04 two times on a virtual machine

Comment: So you mean to not run any executables, nor any file or folder should be opened from 'stable' while on 'unstable'?

Comment: Of course you can do that, but make sure you don't accidently confuse the file systems. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yes! Haha that would be inconvenient indeed! I will try it ou when I get home. On a scale from 1 to 10, how certain are you that my project wont screw anything up during install? Assuming me myself makes all the right moves that is.

Comment: As long as you don't touch the partition with your 'stable' environment during the installation there is not much that can go wrong. If you are going to resize partitions to make space for your your 'unstable' environment I would recommend you to make an image of your hard drive first as this **may** corrupt your FS